# Svelte/Sapper dynamic client-side routing

Tags: svelte

I'm using [Svelte](https://svelte.technology/) and [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.technology/) for a web app where I need to proceed to the next page dynamically, i.e. after something happens (a Web Bluetooth connection) - not just from an `<a>` element click.

For `<a>` links, Sapper intercepts these and performs client-side routing. How can I achieve client-side routing myself, via JavaScript?

If, for example, I call `location.href = ...` then this is not intercepted and it involves a roundtrip to the server for the next page.

Is there a neat way of doing this? (Something like `router.route('/my-page')`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it [here in the docs](https://sapper.svelte.technology/guide#goto-href-options-):

```
import { goto } from 'sapper/runtime.js';
goto('/my-page');
```

Answer (score 7):

For **Svelte-3:**

```
import { goto } from '@sapper/app'
goto('/profiles')
```